# send string by clicking on ListView items

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

in Listview items, i have 3 textview, and i want to send this String values(textviews) by clicking on each item separately.... i mean by clicking on item no.1 , using intent i could reach 4 strings in that item from other activity...here is my code:

```
lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //.
    //. using cursor and attach it to adapter
    //.
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
            new String[]{"_id","address", "body"}, new int[]{
            R.id.textView6, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView7});
    lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);


    lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,otherActivity.class);

            //???message should be ??

            i.putExtra( "MESSAGE" , message);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

thanks...

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, what you need to send to next class? you can use `view.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).getText()` to get the values from text views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

     TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.R.id.textView6);

     //to pass id value             
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,otherActivity.class);
     i.putExtra( "MESSAGE" ,  v.getText());
     startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly your question...Get the text for each textview to a string and send it...

```
lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

String _id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).getText().toString();
String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).getText().toString();
String body = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,otherActivity.class);

            //???message should be ??
            String message = id + address + body;

            i.putExtra( "MESSAGE" , message);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: @hamed don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful. This will help other users find the answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want to pass each item value by click on it then

message should be

```
String message = adapter.getItem(position).toString;
```

edit

```
String message = ((TextView)adapter.getItem(position)).getText().toString();
```